# How to avoid the first navigationview item focused when opening?

Tags: uwp, navigation, focus, uwp-xaml, windows-template-studio

I'm using `Windows Template Studio`, and created a `NavigationView`.

My original thought is creating a navigatoin menu like `Android`, when pressing the `Left` button in a page, open the navigation menu, and focus on the corresponding item.

For example, When I'm in Settings page, and current focus in on a `Button`. When I press `Left` button, the `NavigationView` opens and focus on the `Settings` item.

But now the focus always on the first item, and then go to the corresponding item.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/hupo376787/NaviViewOnXbox) that can reproduce the bug, you can run it on pc/xbox.

You can see the video [here](https://youtu.be/oeKQjcS4oVQ).

So how to avoid the first navigationview item focused when opening?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a default behavior, because the focus of your `NavigationViewItem` is set manually, before setting the focus of a specific item, it does not prevent the default focus behavior of `NavigationView`, like this:

1. Open `NavigationView`
2. The application automatically focuses on MenuItems (the first item is automatically selected)
3. You reset the focus of the option in the `PaneOpened` event.

This operation will indeed cause a focus jump. In order to avoid this, we need to judge when the first item gets focus (using `strNaviTag` as a reference):

**ShellPage.xaml**

```xml
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="People" Tag="main" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" GettingFocus="FirstItem_GettingFocus"/>
```

**ShellPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnItemInvoked(WinUI.NavigationView sender, WinUI.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    // ...
    (Application.Current as App).strNaviTag = item.Tag.ToString();
    // ...
}


private void NavigationViewItem_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    if((Application.Current as App).strNaviTag != "main" 
        && !(args.OldFocusedElement is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem))
    {
        args.TryCancel();
        return;
    }
}
```

This prevents the first item from gaining focus when the requirements are not met.

Thanks.

Comment: This solution almost solved my requirement, except when the focus is on my first page(Main), and open the `NavigationView` menu. Do you have any better improvement?

Comment: Hello, I noticed that in `App.xaml.cs`, `strNaviTag` defaults to an empty string, you can set it to "main".

Comment: It's the same. I think it's because we wrote `strNaviTag != "main" ` in 'NavigationViewItem_GettingFocus'.

Comment: `strNaviTag` is a basis for judgment, but it seems that there are still some shortcomings. Our solution is to prevent the default behavior of `NavigationView` when it is opened (select the first item). On this basis, you can create a more appropriate judgment condition according to your needs.